# Why is my laravel collection returning 500 error even it's not when I checked the results using dd()?

Tags: laravel, collections, datatable, routes, yajra-datatable

I have here a Yajra data table where it shows records based on another data table. Meaning the record of the 1st table, when clicked, shows the records of that record in another inner data table (#tbl-received-items). Currently, I encounter an error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=tbl-received-items - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

And when I saw network tab in chrome, it is 500 error and says:

[image: screenshot.png]

Meaning there's something wrong with the results. Please help me spot the error on my `createReceivedItemsCollection()` function.

I can confirm that my `$collection` is returning a correct collection. Please see the screenshot.

[image: screenshot.png]

Here's my route:

```
Route::get('receiving-history', [ReceivingHistoryController::class, 'index'])->name('receiving-history.index');
Route::get('receiving-history/list', [ReceivingHistoryController::class, 'getReceivingHistory']);
Route::get('receiving-history/{voucher_id}', [ReceivingHistoryController::class, 'show'])->name('receiving-history.show');
Route::get('received-items/list', [ReceivingHistoryController::class, 'getReceivedItems']);
```

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\{
    Product,
    ReceiveItems
};
use DataTables;

class ReceivingHistoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('receiving-history.index');
    }

    public function show(Request $request, ReceiveItems $receive_items) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = $this->createReceivedItemsCollection($request);
            return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
        }
        return view('receiving-history.show', ['receive_items' =>  $receive_items]);
    }

    public function getReceivingHistory(Request $request) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = ReceiveItems::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
        }
    }

    public function getReceivedItems(Request $request) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = $this->createReceivedItemsCollection($request);
            return Datatables::of($data)->toJson();
        }
    }

    public function createReceivedItemsCollection(Request $request) {
        $received_items = ReceiveItems::where('voucher_id', '=', $request->voucher_id)->get();
        foreach($received_items as $received_item) {
            $product_ids = $received_item->product_id;
            $list = []; 
            foreach($product_ids as $product_item_no => $product_id) {
                $products = Product::where('id', '=', $product_id); 
                $voucher_cost = $products->value('cost');
                $qty_addend = $received_item->qty_per_item;

                $list[] = array(
                    'product_item_no' => $product_item_no + 1,
                    'product_id' => $product_id,
                    'product_name' => $products->value('name'),
                    'size' => $products->value('size'),
                    'qty_addend' => $qty_addend[$product_item_no],
                    'voucher_cost' => $voucher_cost,
                    'ext_cost' => number_format($voucher_cost * $qty_addend[$product_item_no], 2)
                );
            }
            $list = (object)$list;
            $collection = collect($list);
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

My datatable JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.noConflict();
    var voucherID = document.cookie;
    // =datatable
    let table = $('#tbl-received-items').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        language: { 
            processing: '<div class="loader-container"><div class="loader"></div></div>'
        },
        ajax: "/received-items/list",
        serverSide: true,
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'product_item_no',
                name: 'product_item_no',
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                orderable: true, 
                searchable: true, 
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 content">' + data + '</span>';
                },
            },
            { 
                data: 'product_name', 
                name: 'product_name', 
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                orderable: true, 
                searchable: true, 
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="'+ getBaseUrl() + '/products/' + row.product_id + '"><div class="text-sm text-gray-900 content">' + data + '</div></a>';
                },  
            },
            { 
                data: 'size', 
                name: 'size',
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="'+ getBaseUrl() + '/products/' + row.product_id + '"><div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 content">' + data + '</div></a>'; 
                },
            },
            { 
                data: 'qty_addend', 
                name: 'qty_addend',
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 col-qty-addend',
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 content">' + data + '</span>'; 
                },
            },
            { 
                data: 'voucher_cost', 
                name: 'voucher_cost',
                orderable: true, 
                searchable: true,
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="'+ getBaseUrl() + '/products/' + row.product_id + '"><div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 content">' + data + '</div></a>'; 
                },
            },
            { 
                data: 'ext_cost', 
                name: 'ext_cost',
                orderable: true, 
                searchable: true,
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 content">' + data + '</span>'; 
                },
            },
        ],
        oLanguage: { sProcessing: "<div id='loader'></div>" },
        footerCallback: function(row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(),
                data;
                
            var intVal = function(i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
            };

            total = api
                .column(5)
                .data()
                .reduce(function(a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);

            $('span#total').text(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-PH', {
                    style: 'currency',
                    currency: 'PHP',
                }).format(total));
        }
    });
});

function getBaseUrl() {
    return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
}
```

Then my HTML table:

```
<table id="tbl-received-items" class="min-w-full tbl-responsive">
    <thead class="bg-gray-50">
        <tr>
            <th
                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                Product Item #
            </th>
            <th
                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                Product Name
            </th>
            <th
                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                Size
            </th>
            <th
                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                Qty
            </th>
            <th
                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                Voucher Cost
            </th>
            <th
                class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                Ext. Cost
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="bg-white">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding an onclick event on the 1st datatable that sets localstorage with the voucher ID. Also, I set the it to POST as to pass the data.

```
 $('#tbl-receiving-history').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $voucher_id = $(this).attr('data-voucher-id');
        sessionStorage.clear(); //clear first before setting localstorage
        localStorage.setItem("data-voucher-id", $voucher_id);
    } );
```

Then on the second table, I just retrieve the value of the localstorage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.noConflict();
    $voucher_id = localStorage.getItem('data-voucher-id');
    // =datatable
    let table = $('#tbl-received-items').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        language: { 
            processing: '<div class="loader-container"><div class="loader"></div></div>'
        },
        ajax: '/receiving-history/' + $voucher_id +  '/list',
        serverSide: true,
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'product_item_no',
                name: 'product_item_no',
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                orderable: true, 
                searchable: true, 
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 content">' + data + '</span>';
                },
            },
            { 
                data: 'product_name', 
                name: 'product_name', 
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                orderable: true, 
                searchable: true, 
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="'+ getBaseUrl() + '/products/' + row.product_id + '"><div class="text-sm text-gray-900 content">' + data + '</div></a>';
                },  
            },
            { 
                data: 'size', 
                name: 'size',
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="'+ getBaseUrl() + '/products/' + row.product_id + '"><div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 content">' + data + '</div></a>'; 
                },
            },
            { 
                data: 'qty_addend', 
                name: 'qty_addend',
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200 col-qty-addend',
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 content">' + data + '</span>'; 
                },
            },
            { 
                data: 'voucher_cost', 
                name: 'voucher_cost',
                orderable: true, 
                searchable: true,
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="'+ getBaseUrl() + '/products/' + row.product_id + '"><div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 content">' + data + '</div></a>'; 
                },
            },
            { 
                data: 'ext_cost', 
                name: 'ext_cost',
                orderable: true, 
                searchable: true,
                className: 'px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap border-b border-gray-200',
                render : function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 content">' + data + '</span>'; 
                },
            },
        ],
        oLanguage: { sProcessing: "<div id='loader'></div>" },
        createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
            if(Math.sign(data.qty_addend) == -1) $(row).addClass('bg-red-200');
        },
        footerCallback: function(row, data, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(),
                data;
                
            var intVal = function(i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
            };

            total = api
                .column(5)
                .data()
                .reduce(function(a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0);

            $('span#total').text(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-PH', {
                    style: 'currency',
                    currency: 'PHP',
                }).format(total));
        }
    });
});

function getBaseUrl() {
    return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
}
```